# Android TextView set to match parent extending past parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Why is the TextView with the bio extending way past the edge of the screen when it, and all of its parents, are set to match_parent?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Leroy Satchel Paige"
            android:textSize="42sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:fontFamily="serif"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/imgSatchelPaige"
            android:contentDescription="Satchel Paige in Uniform"
            android:layout_width="275dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/digital_five" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtBio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/bio"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:singleLine="false" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: first of all declare parent layout orientation

Comment: @Rohit do you mean that there is difference between `match_parent` and `fill_parent`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using weight and textview will fit
and make the orientation of layout horizontal

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/imgSatchelPaige"
            android:contentDescription="Satchel Paige in Uniform"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/digital_five" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtBio"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/bio"
            android:textSize="24sp"
                 android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:singleLine="false" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap all of you layout to have space to the TextView

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Leroy Satchel Paige"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSatchelPaige"
            android:layout_width="275dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:contentDescription="Satchel Paige in Uniform"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/edward2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtBio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Leroy Satchel Paige"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this layout it fits your requirements..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Leroy Satchel Paige"
        android:textSize="42sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:fontFamily="serif"/>

  </LinearLayout>



    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imgSatchelPaige"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll1"
        android:contentDescription="Satchel Paige in Uniform"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/digital_five" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtBio"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgSatchelPaige"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bio"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:singleLine="false" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Also you are unnecessarily nesting linear layouts which could have overdraw issues in your app.